# How can I set random speeds once inside Update?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spin : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(1, 500)]
    public float[] speeds;
    public bool randomSpeed = false;

    private GameObject[] objectsToSpin;
    private bool randomSpeedInUpdate = true;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public void Init()
    {
        objectsToSpin = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("ClonedObj");
        if (objectsToSpin.Length > 0)
        {
            speeds = new float[objectsToSpin.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < objectsToSpin.Length; i++)
            {
                if (randomSpeed == true)
                {
                    speeds[i] = Random.Range(1, 500);
                }
                else
                {
                    speeds[i] = 100;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (objectsToSpin.Length > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < objectsToSpin.Length; i++)
            {
                objectsToSpin[i].transform.Rotate(Vector3.down, speeds[i] * Time.deltaTime);

                if (randomSpeed == true && randomSpeedInUpdate == true)
                {
                    speeds[i] = Random.Range(1, 500);
                    randomSpeedInUpdate = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    speeds[i] = 100;
                    randomSpeedInUpdate = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to use a helper flag variable name randomSpeedInUpdate but still when I'm changing the randomSpeed flag to true while the game is running it keep changing the speeds all the time. I want it will change the speeds to random only once when changing it to true.

Comment: Try walking through your code one instruction at a time, exactly how the processor would do it. You'll find very quickly why it keeps recalculating the speeds - because that's exactly what you told it you wanted it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your Update function to

```
void Update()
{
    if (randomSpeed && randomSpeedInUpdate)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < speeds.Length; i++)
        {
            speeds[i] = Random.Range(1, 500);

            if (i == speeds.Length - 1)
                randomSpeedInUpdate = false;
        }
    }
    else if (!randomSpeed)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < speeds.Length; i++)
        {
            speeds[i] = 100;
        }
        randomSpeedInUpdate = true;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < objectsToSpin.Length; i++)
    {
        objectsToSpin[i].transform.Rotate(Vector3.down, speeds[i] * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```